# Using MEF in a windows service?

Tags: windows-services, mef

I'd like to use MEF in a windows service / WCF service.

The configuration of the AggregateCatalog is no problem, but what do I do with the methods CreateShell() and InitializeShell()? The service can't have a shell, so do I just return null?

And where would I create and run the bootstrapper? In OnStart of the Service class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MEF doesn't have CreateShell and InitializeShell methods.  I think those are methods that Prism uses.  Prism is a UI application framework which uses MEF.  Since you are writing a service, you wouldn't use Prism, but you could use MEF.

Create a `CompositionContainer` connected to the catalog you've created, and then you can pull exports from the container.

Comment: Oh. So for MEF alone I don't even need a bootstrapper class?

Comment: Aah, finally managed to reduce the usage from Prism to MEF itself. Thanks for the pointer.